# Eclipse: Import Maven project, missing maven-gae-plugin

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin

Coming from Visual Studio, I'm pretty new to the Eclipse IDE.
And finding it very difficult. I seem to get error messages of the type "missing ..." a *LOT*.

The latest issue I'm having, where I just can't get around is this:
I"m trying to compile & run this sample project: http://code.google.com/p/gwtgae2011/

1. When I choose "checkout maven projects from SCM" my SCM drop down is empty...
   So I just checked it out with Hg manually. No problem.
2. Trying Import > Existing Maven Project. Seems to read the pom.xml alright, but shows an error:
   **"No marketplace entries found to handle maven-gae-plugin:0.8.1:unpack in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information."**

Since I can't find it through updates or market within eclipse I downloaded maven-gae-plugin (http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/downloads/list). I figured just dropping it into the "plugins" or "dropins" folder should be enough. Apparently not so...

Question: How do I fix this error?
*(I tried both 3.6 & 3.7)*

Links to some good eclipse tutorials covering these kinds of topics are very welcome too!

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

`maven-gae-plugin` is in central repo so it should be found.

Did you set the path to your local repo? http://united-coders.com/phillip-steffensen/maven-2-part-3-configuring-eclipse-for-apache-maven-2-projects

Comment: Thanks. I've checked, that everything is setup properly according to the website. But the problem still persists.
**Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.8.4:unpack (execution: install-server-jar, phase: validate) pom.xml /gwtgae2011 line 394 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem**

The "mvn eclipse:eclipse" command helped a lot though to track down issues. I corrected a few version numbers to reduce errors.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error, what worked for me was:

- Comment the plugin
- Import into eclipse
- Uncomment the plugin
- Discover an error in the plugin XML
- Fix error found in the plugin XML

I am not certain, but it seems like this is a unclear error that something about the pom.xml is invalid.