# gwt - Error when importing a gwt project using Maven import in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven, import, gwt-maven-plugin

I am using `Eclipse`, `Version: Indigo Service Release 1`.

My `GWT version is 2.4.0`. I installed everything like GWT and Maven related plugins.

I am trying to import a `existing gwt-maven project`. When importing, I see this dialog:

[image: error when importing]

Can anyone tell me why and how to solve it?

Comment: have you installed M2E ? http://eclipse.org/m2e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your dear friend.

By entering "no marketplace entries found to handle gwt-mavn-plugin", I got:

[Error when importing Maven-GWT project ("No marketplace entries found to handle gwt-maven-plugin")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916308/error-when-importing-maven-gwt-project-no-marketplace-entries-found-to-handle)

[gwt-maven-plugin with Eclipse Indigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410338/gwt-maven-plugin-with-eclipse-indigo)

[Eclipse: Import Maven project, missing maven-gae-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742979/eclipse-import-maven-project-missing-maven-gae-plugin)

**EDIT :**

Actually I would advise you to use `maven` from the command line instead of using the `Maven plugin` in Eclipse as I had exprienced many issues with it.

From the command line, run the following commands:

- To compile and install : `mvn clean install`
- to generate eclipse project: `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

Afterwards, from your eclipse, import your generated project as a normal project and voila!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the links. I did google it. But none of them solved my problem. For the first link, there is no answer actually. none of the answers are correct. you can find it when you read the comment. For the second link you gave, the answer is talking about giving up Maven and manually do things. as I am working with other team mate, I can't do that and I have to keep consistency with mates. For the 3rd link, mine is about maven-gwt, not maven-gae, and again, no correct answers for that question even.